# react-select compatible with React 16?

Tags: reactjs, react-select

I'm trying to use react-select v1.0.0-rc.9 with react v16.0.0.  Are those two supposed to work together?  Just following the simple example from Github, I get this error:
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Indeed the v1.0.0-rc.9 version of react-select does not work with React 16, because since version 16, React requires to import the PropTypes from the `prop-types` package (see https://reactjs.org/docs/typechecking-with-proptypes.html for more information).

The fix has been merged and is available in version v2.0.0-alpha.2 :
https://github.com/JedWatson/react-select/commit/8ff4596259ab4a42df95185729a35599313e571e